# JQuery won't show hebrew in text input

Tags: jquery, utf-8

I have an input which it's value is "full name" or "שם מלא" in hebrew.
I'm trying to fill the text area again if the user didn't enter any characters, but when i do it, it shows me some unknown signs in the text input.
the meta charset is defined as "utf-8".
here is the jq code:

```
$('input').click(function () {

    $temp = $(this);
    $(this).val('');

    }


);

$('[name=fullname]').on("focusout", function () {

    if ($('[name=fullname]').val() === '') {
        $('[name=fullname]').val('שם מלא');

    }
}
    );
```

the html code:

```
                        <form>

                                <input type="text" name="fullname" value="שם מלא" />


                        </form>
```

THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: Works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/nLvf4773/

Comment: is your page encoded in utf8? I mean when you save file on server. And what's wrong with placeholder attribute?